# Query doubles amount on count for certain results

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query where I am trying to display the results and count the amount of replies per topic. The result sometimes doubles the amount of replies. Instead of having 10 it will display 20. Is there something I am missing in my query that would be doubling it?

```
SELECT      
        count(replies.reply_topic) as replyCount,
        topics.topic_id,
        topics.topic_subject,
        topics.topic_date,
        topics.topic_cat,
        topics.topic_picture,
        topics.topic_creator,
        topics.topic_likes,
        users.user_id,
        users.username,
        profile.profile_id,
        profile.profile_pictureMain,
        profile.profile_users,
        savelink.saveLink_id,
        savelink.saveUser_id,
        savelink.link_id,
        votelikes.voteLikes_user,
        votelikes.voteLikes_topic,
        votelikes.voteLikes_hot,
        votelikes.voteLikes_cold
        FROM
            topics
        LEFT JOIN
            replies
        ON
            replies.reply_topic = topics.topic_id
        LEFT JOIN
            users
        ON
            topics.topic_creator = users.user_id
        LEFT JOIN
            profile
        ON
            profile.profile_users = users.user_id
        LEFT JOIN
            savelink
        ON
            savelink.link_id = topics.topic_id
        LEFT JOIN
            votelikes
        ON
            votelikes.voteLikes_topic = topics.topic_id
        GROUP BY
            topics.topic_id
        ORDER BY
            topics.topic_date DESC 
        LIMIT ?, ?
```

So here is my reply table: where the reply_topic is the id of the topic that was replied too, and it displays twice as many.

```
reply_id   reply_content    reply_topic    reply_by

1           stuff            45             34
2           more stuff       76             21
3           more             45             75
```

displaying the replies like so:

```
<i class="fa fa-comments"></i> '.$row['replyCount'].' Comments</a>
```

and instead of displaying (2) results for reply_topic 45 it displays (4)
and so on.

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images!

Comment: Your `GROUP BY` columns and `SELECT` columns are simply not compatible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `count(distinct replies.reply_topic)`

```
SELECT      
        count(distinct replies.reply_topic) as replyCount,
        topics.topic_id,
        topics.topic_subject,
        topics.topic_date,
        topics.topic_cat,
        topics.topic_picture,
        topics.topic_creator,
        topics.topic_likes,
        users.user_id,
        users.username,
        profile.profile_id,
        profile.profile_pictureMain,
        profile.profile_users,
        savelink.saveLink_id,
        savelink.saveUser_id,
        savelink.link_id,
        votelikes.voteLikes_user,
        votelikes.voteLikes_topic,
        votelikes.voteLikes_hot,
        votelikes.voteLikes_cold
        FROM
            topics
        LEFT JOIN
            replies
        ON
            replies.reply_topic = topics.topic_id
        LEFT JOIN
            users
        ON
            topics.topic_creator = users.user_id
        LEFT JOIN
            profile
        ON
            profile.profile_users = users.user_id
        LEFT JOIN
            savelink
        ON
            savelink.link_id = topics.topic_id
        LEFT JOIN
            votelikes
        ON
            votelikes.voteLikes_topic = topics.topic_id
        GROUP BY
            topics.topic_id
        ORDER BY
            topics.topic_date DESC 
        LIMIT ?, ?
```

Comment: Thanks for the help @fa06, I had tried that previously but it only returns a single value for each result.

Comment: then provide your sample data in your question @Stuckfornow